# How to conditionally append pandas series to another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, append

I have two data frames, one that is names of people born and their frequencies in each year (1880-2017).

```
name    gender  frequency  year
Mary       F       7065    1880
Anna       F       2604    1880
Emma       F       2003    1880
Elizabeth  F       1939    1880
Minnie     F       1746    1880
...
```

and the other is years and the total number of births (1880-2017).

```
 birth_year    Male    Female   Total
     1880     118400    97605  216005
     1881     108282    98855  207137
     1882     122031   115695  237726
     1883     112477   120059  232536
     1884     122738   137586  260324
...
```

These data frames are not the same size but I want to append the columns from the second data frame to the first data frame if the birth year is the same in order to include percentage population. I want to do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(all_names_nat_DF)):
    for j in range(len(total_births)):
        if all_names_nat_DF['year'][i] == total_births['birth_year']:
            all_names_nat_DF.append(total_births['birth_year'][j])
```

But with this I get the error `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: Try with merge .

Comment: What you're looking for is the concept of `joining`, which matches dataframes on a `key column` which is in your case `birth_year`. In pandas we use `merge` for that. I linked a nice Q&A explaining this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use `df.merge`:

```py
df

    name gender frequency year
0   Mary    F   7065    1880
1   Anna    F   2604    1880
2   Emma    F   2003    1880
3   Eliz    F   1939    1880
4   Minnie  F   1746    1880


births

  birth_year  Male  Female  Total
0   1880    118400  97605   216005
1   1881    108282  98855   207137
2   1882    122031  115695  237726
3   1883    112477  120059  232536
4   1884    122738  137586  260324

df.merge(births, how='inner', left_on='year', right_on='birth_year')

    name gender frequency year birth_year Male  Female  Total
0   Mary    F   7065    1880    1880    118400  97605   216005
1   Anna    F   2604    1880    1880    118400  97605   216005
2   Emma    F   2003    1880    1880    118400  97605   216005
3   Eliz    F   1939    1880    1880    118400  97605   216005
4   Minnie  F   1746    1880    1880    118400  97605   216005
```

Comment: Ishan Saraswat that looks like it worked thank you! May I ask how you knew to join left on year and right on birth_year? That isn't intuitive to me for some reason.

Comment: @NathanCahn the ````left_on```` and ````right_on```` arguments simply denote the column or index level names to join on. If both the left and the right dataframes had a column named 'year', you could instead simply use the ````on```` argument (````on='year'````). The 'left' dataframe in this case would the one that you're calling merge on so in the line ````df.merge(births....)```` df is the left dataframe and births is the right dataframe. Refer to: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: that clears it up thank you for your help!